# Opening epub using zathura 18.04

Tags: epub

I have downloaded zathura doc viewer. But it supports only pdf rightnow. But in archlinux wiki, they have this plugin for opening epub. But this is not available in ubuntu. I saw a PPA, but it doesn't have support for 18.04. How to get this?

Answer (score 7):

As far I can read from ArchWiki - you need to install [`zathura-pdf-mupdf`](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/community/x86_64/zathura-pdf-mupdf/) plugin.

Currently there is a PPA named [`ppa:spvkgn/zathura-mupdf`](https://launchpad.net/~spvkgn/+archive/ubuntu/zathura-mupdf).

After contacting PPA owner we have package for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

So if you have followed my [previous method](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1145187/3), then you can delete the pin/lock file and install binary packages from the repository as usual:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-zathura

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:spvkgn/zathura-mupdf

sudo apt-get install zathura zathura-pdf-mupdf
```

and enjoy!

Comment: thanks for that, now I can open epub. But I am gettings these errors => "theme parsing error" while opening the files". Any workaround for that?

Comment: They are only warnings, so you can ignore them :)

Comment: can you tell me how to copy the text while viewing a file? I tried this 'set selection-clipboard clipboard' after a suggestion from a forum, but still it doesn't let me copy text.

Comment: I have never used Zathura, so I can not help with its interface.

Comment: @user9370227 the binary package is published 7 hours ago. See updated answer, and if it helps accept it :)

Comment: @N0rbert I tried this (this is a year later, I know), and I'm getting a "no valid OpenPGP data found" error. Do you know why this is/how to fix it?

Comment: It may be network issue or something related. Try to run `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F2C37BD8BDF01321549242C9AEC82AC78B65E182` manually.

Comment: @N0rbert ok cool, I tried that, it says it the key was imported. I tried running the second to last command, but I get `gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp_acqzb9o/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmp_acqzb9o/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key AEC82AC78B65E182: public key "Launchpad PPA for pavel" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.`. Then I tried the last command, returning `Unable to located package zathura-pdf-mupdf`. Also, I'm on debian buster, if that helps

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` after adding the key. And then use `sudo apt-get install zathura zathura-pdf-mupdf` .

Comment: PPA not working with 22 LTS

Comment: Thank you... even for fedora it's the same... Well now I have alternative for SumatraPDF on Linux...