# Zathura EPUB support issue : "Unknown file type: 'application/zip'"

Tags: document, epub, zathura

so the [archwiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Zathura#Installation) explains that zathura needs the package `zathura-pdf-mupdf` for EPUB support.

And this askubuntu [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1145153/opening-epub-using-zathura-18-04) seems to confirm it works on Ubuntu too.

So I have installed the package thanks to the PPA mentioned in the askubuntu post :

```
user@host :~/Downloads/test $ > dpkg -s zathura-pdf-mupdf | grep Status
Status: install ok installed
```

```
user@host :~/Downloads/test $ > zathura --version
zathura 0.4.3
girara 0.3.2 (runtime: 0.3.2)
(plugin) pdf-mupdf (0.3.4) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/zathura/libpdf-mupdf.so)
```

And downloaded an example .epub file "Alice in Wonderland" from [here](https://www.adobe.com/solutions/ebook/digital-editions/sample-ebook-library.html).

As you can see below, the file seems to be correctly recognized as an EPUB by my system (as listed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Common_types)) :

```
user@host :~/Downloads/test $ > xdg-mime query filetype aliceDynamic.epub 
application/epub+zip
```

However, `zathura` looks like it doesn't recognize it as such, and is unable to read the file, even with the `zathura-pdf-mupdf` package :

```
user@host :~/Downloads/test $ > zathura aliceDynamic.epub 
error: Unknown file type: 'application/zip'
```

Do you know what could be the issue ?

System :

- Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: Are you running a terminal from within Emacs? It would be worth trying to open your EPUB from a regular terminal (gnome terminal, etc.).

Comment: No, this is only an indicator in the prompt that readline is in Emacs mode (the default, which you are on if you have not `set -o vi`)

Answer (score 1):

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EPUB `epub` file is a zip archive with many files inside . This is a very common design choice , example  `JAR` files are also a zip file .

A solution to fix , is to convert the adobe file EPUB to a EPUB that is readable by zathura .

I tested with `calibre` , so you need :

- import the adobe version into the calibre library
- convert
- save to disk

or

- look in the folder `Calibre Library`  in you home dir

you will a epub file and the original epub

This solution was tested on Ubuntu 18.04 lts with same packages you propose .

Comment: I can open the EPUB from zathura without converting.

Comment: which version of zathura ? on which version of ubuntu ?

Comment: Can you explain what is this supposed to be changing ? How would zathura behave better with this "new epub" ? What is the rationale behind it ? My zathura can't read any epub as is (I tested several files).  Or is it just an empirical law you just happened to come across ?

Comment: @MarianMinar So you will come to "brag" that it works for you but not give a single information on your system ? Do you understand what stackexchange is supposed to be ?

Comment: @Atrab  i tested  on ubuntu 18.04 with you book  by installing  packages from the repo you gave